# show date in three combo boxes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, combobox

I am beginner in .net. I need to show `day`, `month` and `year` in three different comboboxes. To make them fill i was trying hardcoded values from 1950 to present year. which i later realized that i need to check for also ferbruary(28 days), leap year and other issues. Is there any other way to do this without hardcoding the values.

while searching for answer on internet i came across datepicker and monthcalendar which i dont want to use(because my project should be unique from my other friends who are using datepicker and monthcalendar). or else if you have any other suggestions instead of comboboxes please share.

[image]

I am sure someone has asked this question before. I dont mind if you direct the link.

EDITED after *nikhil agrawal's* answer:

**Working Code:**

```
cmbDay    --->  combobox
cmbMonth  --->  combobox
cmbYear   --->  combobox
```

*FormLoad event*

```
        this.cmbYear.Leave+=new EventHandler(cmbYear_Leave);
        this.cmbDay.Leave += new EventHandler(cmbYear_Leave);
        this.cmbMonth.Leave += new EventHandler(cmbYear_Leave);
        //
        for (int i = 1950; i < 2012; i++)
        {
            cmbYear.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++)
        {
            cmbDay.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }
        //
        cmbDay.SelectedIndex = 0;
        cmbMonth.SelectedIndex = 0;
        cmbYear.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

*OnLeave Event*

```
private void cmbYear_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int day = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Convert.ToInt32(cmbYear.Text), cmbMonth.SelectedIndex+1);                       
        if (day <= cmbDay.SelectedIndex)
        {
            //alert message or your managing code.
        }
    }
```

PS: `cmbMonth` is in string format ("Jan","Feb","Mar",...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Populate all three with all possible values like for date 1 to 31, for month Jan to Dec and year 1950 to present year.

Check for valid date when lost focus on all three using

```
DateTime.DaysInMonth(int year, int month);
```

for year you can directly cast selected item to int and for month you can find selectedindex +1 (coz index is 0 based).

Now on lost focus(one single lost focus event on all three's lost focus) check if the date is less or equal to days returned by method. If not then alert message or something.

Comment: Yes, that's even easier solution that I wanted to post

Comment: I dont understand the concept of keeping single lost focus event on all three comboboxes. how to do that.

Comment: Write one method and hook all combobox to refer to same event.

Answer (score 1):

I think do you want to populate the day combo box values based on month specification.
You can try this code. It may helps you. You write a cmbobox selectedIndexChange event in that write this code.

```
 if(cmbMonth.Text=="feb")  //if(cmbMonth.SelectedIndex.Equals(specify index))
  {
    for(i=0;i<29;i++)
    {
       cmbDay.Item.Add(i.ToString());
    }
  }
  else
   {
    for(i=1;i<32;i++)
    {
       cmbDay.Item.Add(i.ToString());
    }
   }
```

like that you can do other months validations also.

Answer (score 0):

write
s of Item in for loop statements

like
cmbDay.Items.Add(i.ToString());
cmbDay.Items.Add(i.ToString());