# Fill combobox with dates (only years and months)?

Tags: c#, datetime, combobox

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
dates.Add(now);
dates.Add(now.AddMonths(6));
dates.Add(now.AddMonths(1));
dates.Add(now.AddYears(1));

comboBoxDates.DataSource = dates;
```

I would use a loop and go through the list, and make another list without the days and house:minutes.. but I'm sure there are better ways to do this.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This [**Link**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12872488/1577396) might be helpful to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve, but in general, you can bind `List<DateTime>` to your combobox like you do it and then just set its `FormatString` to whatever you need:

```
comboBoxDates.FormatString = "MM-yyyy";
```

This approach allows you to configure what is being displayed to users, and in code you can still work with `DateTime` bound.